# Create paypal sandbox account to use for different clients

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am working with WordPress and will be setting up online shops using PayPal for multiple clients.

Can I create a single PayPal Sandbox Developer Account through my personal PayPal merchant account and then use that to test my integrations for different clients? In other words, I want all the transaction emails to come to me while testing and not to my clients.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if you're using IPN or not but you can do this with passing over the receiver email, in this case you. {can insert as many as you like} https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

Answer (score 0):

If sites are all going to create the same call then yes, that what I normally do, Il include my PayPal login and once I'm done testing I simply include the client PayPal login instead.